# c# and xml-rpc.net: mismatch exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm using xml-rpc.net to access an e-commerce site (php) from an c# application. The code:

```
String[] fooResourcesReturn = FoobarProxy.resources(fooLoginReturn);
```

returns the following XmlRpcTypeMismatchException:

```
response contains struct value where string expected (as type String) [response : array mapped to type String[] : element 0]
```

The problem is that the method resources returns an array but I cannot figure out its type. I've used string[] but obviously that's not correct. Here's the def for resources:

```
    [XmlRpcMethod("resources")]
    String[] resources(String sessionId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you figured this out? #1 You want to match your structure to the response. 
If you use a struct like

```
public struct ResourcesResult{
   public string[] resources;
}
```

it should work assuming the return has an array element called `resources` with `string` values.

Please let me know if you've resolved it. We can talk some more.